# Can't Open page with facebook plugin casperJS

Tags: javascript, facebook, phantomjs, casperjs

I try to open page where we use facebook plugin, but casperJS does not load it. How to load pages with facebook plugin?

```
var casper = require("casper").create({
          verbose: true,
          logLevel: 'debug',
          pageSettings: {
            userAgent: 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:17.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/17.0'
          }
        }),
        utils = require('utils');

    casper.start();

    casper.thenOpen('http://bookmate.com', function(response) {
      this.echo(this.getTitle());
    });

    casper.run(function() {
      console.log('End');
      casper.exit();
    });
```

result:

```
[info] [phantom] Starting...
[info] [phantom] Running suite: 2 steps
[debug] [phantom] opening url: http://bookmate.com/, HTTP GET
[debug] [phantom] Navigation requested: url=http://bookmate.com/, type=Other, willNavigate=true, isMainFrame=true
[debug] [phantom] url changed to "http://bookmate.com/"
[debug] [phantom] Navigation requested: url=https://www.facebook.com/plugins/facepile.php?app_id=124791507543584&href=http://facebook.com/bookmate&action=like&width&height=70&max_rows=1&colorscheme=light&size=medium&show_count=true, type=Other, willNavigate=true, isMainFrame=false
```

I try to open page where we use facebook plugin, but casperJS does not load it. How to load pages with facebook plugin?

Comment: I tried to abort the request, but it doesn't seems to work http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/events-filters.html#page-resource-requested

Answer (score 1):

The issue is not actually with CasperJS but with PhantomJS. The same script works fine when you run against a SlimerJS engine.

I tried to open the page on phantomjs using the below script and see that it hangs.

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
var url = 'http://bookmate.com/';
page.open(url, function (status) {
  //Page is loaded!
  phantom.exit();
});
```